# Смещение в xcode 5

Tags: xcode, ios, mac

можно ли как нибудь вернуть все как было в xcode 5?  все проекты были сделаны для iOS 6 в xcode 4, а после обновления все размеры изменились, шрифты тоже стали больше размером, бары перекрасились....как все вернуть обратно?

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял вопрос. В свойствах XIB **Interface Builder Document** -> **View as** выставить **iOS 6.1 and Earlier**